# Angular 9 - Form not valid onInit if input autofilled by Browser

Tags: angular, forms, autofill

So I noticed a lot of threads about this, but all older and there wasn't an official solution.
Maybe now there is a solution for this problem.
But basically if you have a form with a username input field, when the page loads the first time, if the browser autofills that value (Because you saved your credentials in your browser), the "`login`" button will be still disabled because the form is still invalid until the users clicks anywhere for the first time.

The latest proposed solution I found was using Angular official: `AutofillMonitor`
But it doesnt work:

```
 @ViewChild("email") inputEl: ElementRef;

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private _autofill: AutofillMonitor
  ){
    this.emailForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        userLogin: [
          "",
          {
            validators: [Validators.required],
          },
        ],
        password: [
          "",
          {}
        ]
      }
    );
  }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._autofill.monitor(this.inputEl)
    .subscribe(e => {
        if (e.isAutofilled) {
          // this works, the code gets in here onInit
        this.forceValidityCheck();
        }
      }
    );
  }

forceValidityCheck() {
    this.emailForm.controls["userLogin"].updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<ng-container>
      <form [formGroup]="emailForm" (ngSubmit)="checkAndLoadUserInfo(emailForm.get('userLogin').value)">
      <mat-form-field appearance="standard" class="standardInputField">
        <mat-label translate>enter_email.username</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="userLogin" #email type="email" placeholder="name@example.org" (keyup.enter)="checkAndLoadUserInfo(emailForm.get('userLogin').value)" autofocus autocomplete="username">
        <label class="pswValidationLabels" *ngIf="emailForm.get('userLogin').hasError('doesNotExist')" translate>
          enter_email.unknown_user
          </label>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="standard" class="hiddenFormField">
      <input matInput type="password" autocomplete="current-password">
      </mat-form-field>

      <div>
        <button [disabled]="!emailForm.get('userLogin').valid" mat-raised-button>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
    </ng-container>
```

But the form stays invalid even like this, until the users clicks anywhere on the screen, then it gets valid.

Is there an official solution for this?

Comment: Share the `html` code  also

Comment: If you print `this.emailForm.valid` after `forceValidityCheck`, what does it say?

Comment: @SRana added html code

Comment: @MarcellKiss "not valid"

Comment: try this `[disabled]="emailForm.invalid && emailForm.touched"`

Comment: After executing `forceValidityCheck`, please `console.log` the followings, and let us know the results:
`this.emailForm.valid`, `this.emailForm.touched`, `this.emailForm.value`

Comment: @SRana ok I think you got it! didn't think about "touched" value. This works, because it enables my button, and if the user presses "Enter" when the page loads, it will submit the form with the autofilled value! nice catch! if you put it as answer I ll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

I do see some approvements that may help, because I don't experience your issue.

First, who do you bind the disabled property of the submit button to the validity of the username field only and not the entire form?

Also, I think you ngSubmit is can be a little bit hard to maintain this way, because again, you explicitly use the username field value to pass, while the entire form is available for you in the TS file. So the `checkAndLoadUserInfo()` should not require a parameter.

Then I believe the form build is somewhat 'the old' way to create reactive forms, have you seen that you can create a form control? It works the same way:

```js
this.newGameForm = new FormGroup({
    userLogin: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
    ])
});
```

Now what I always do, is create a function called `initForm()` or something similar and call that from the `ngOnInit()`. Once that is done, you have an instance of your form. You can now easily manipulate form values by setting them like so:

```js
this.formName.patchValue({ userLogin: 'new value'});
```

In case you should already be able to get the value from somewhere at the time you init the form, you could also use the first parameter to create the form with the initial value in the desired field. Both ways will trigger validation and update the form's state.

Comment: I already tried previously with patchValue as I found it in another thread but it didn't work correctly. About the binding to the validity of the username, I do this because here the user doesn't input the password, it is a hidden field, he inputs only username, which gets checked for validity with an API call, only then, if the username is present in the DB, he gets asked the password! Anyway I solved it as a user suggested, by putting also : "&& this.emailForm.touched" in the Disabled property! Then, is there a real difference between the "old way" with form build, and using your syntax?

Comment: I'm not sure about your second question, but is saves you from having to inject the formbuilder. You can still apply the validation on your entire form, because you didn't define any validation rules on your password field. The form becomes valid as soon as all fields are valid and since there are no validation rules on the password field, the form becomes valid as soon as the username field is valid.

Comment: I created a stackblitz for you so you can see it in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ln2git